# Clarification on the concept of a cumulative distribution function of a measure (measure theory)

Tags: self-study, measure-theory

> I was asked to show that $g_f(x)=\mu(f\leq x)$ defines a cumulative
>   distribution function for any measurable function $f$.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ a measurable space. As far as I understand, $\mu(f\leq x)=\mu(\{w\in\Omega:f(w)\leq x\})=\mu(f^{-1}(-\infty, x])$ for $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Given these measurable spaces, $f$ induces the pushforward measure on $\mathcal{B}$ defined by $\mu_f((-\infty, x])=\mu(f^{-1}(-\infty, x])$. But to make $F_{\mu_f}(x)=\mu_f((-\infty, x])$ to be the cumulative distribution function of $\mu_f$, I think it is needed that $\mu$ be finite.

Is my argument going in the right direction?

I'm feeling that something is missing there. Could someone organize the concept of CDF associated to a measure for a better understanding?

Thanks in advance!

---

The definition I hve for a cumulative distribuition function is as follows:

Let $I=[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{B}(I)$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(I,\mathcal{B}(I))$. A **cumulative distribution function** of $\mu$ is a function $g_{\mu}:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g_{\mu}(x)=\mu[a,x],\forall x \in I$.

The definition above seems to require that the original statement be restricted to

> Show that $g_f(x)=\mu(f\leq x)$ defines a cumulative
>   distribution function for any measurable function $f:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow (I,\mathcal{B}(I)) $ and any $\mu$ finite on $\mathcal{F}$.

So if I assume $f:\Omega\rightarrow I, (\mathcal{F},\mathcal{B}(I))$-measurable and assume $\mu$ finite on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, then $\mu_f=\mu\circ f^{-1}$ will be finite on $(I,\mathcal{B}(I))$ and I might finish the proof, on the lines of my argument above.

Comment: Unless $\mu$ is a probability measure, the conclusion is false.  Thus, you had better assume $\mu$ is finite!  One way to proceed is to show that the set function $\nu([a,x])=g_f(x)$ determines a finite measure on $(I,\mathcal{B}(I)).$

Comment: @whuber I believe I need to assume $v$ finite on $(I,\mathcal{B}(I))$. Moreover, to $F_{\mu_f}$ be a CDF under the definition I gave, I need to define $f:\Omega \rightarrow I$, right?

Comment: @whuber Is this kind of question more suitable here or on math exchange?

Comment: It depends on the kind of answers you are looking for.  Because you are couching your questions very mathematically, you might prefer the purely mathematical answers you would get on the Math site.  If you are aiming ultimately to apply what you are learning to statistics, you might appreciate the answers from statisticians you would get here.